# Expected value of a recursive dice game

Tags: probability, dice

---

### Context:

Consider a dice game that is played with a fair, six sided die. You are handed the die, and asked to roll.

- If you roll a 2, 3 or 5, then you take double the face value of the the roll, and are able to roll again.
- If you roll a 4 or 6, then you take your current winnings
- If you roll a 1, then you lose everything

Determine the expected value of playing the game.

For reference, I am currently refreshing my knowledge of probability theory before an upcoming course, and I am somewhat stuck on this problem.

---

### Working:

Intuitively, this seems like a problem that I can solve by conditioning on the first roll, and exploiting symmetry to solve for $\mathbb{E}(X)$. That is, if we let random variable $X$ represent the payoff from playing the game, then;

$$
\begin{align*}
\mathbb{E}(X) &= \sum_{v \in \{1, 2, \dots,6 \}} \mathbb{P}(v) \mathbb{E}(X|v) \\
&= \frac{1}{6}\left( \sum_{v \in \{1, \dots, 6\}} \mathbb{E}(X|v)\right)
\end{align*}
$$

Now, if $v \in \{2, 3, 5 \}$ then $\mathbb{E}(X|v) = 2v + \mathbb{E}(X)$ (this follows from symmetry), so we can simplify the above to:
$$
\mathbb{E}(X) =\frac{1}{6} \left( 20 + 3\mathbb{E}(X) + \sum_{v \in \{ 4, 5, 6\}} \mathbb{E}(X|v)\right)
$$

I'm confident with what I have up to here, but now I struggle to proceed; I am unable to formulate $\mathbb{E}(X|4)$, $\mathbb{E}(X|6)$, or $\mathbb{E}(X|1)$.

I would like an explanation for how I can formulate these three expressions in terms of constants, and $\mathbb{E}(X)$.

Thanks alot!

Comment: You have two different payouts for throwing a $5$, and no payout for throwing a $1$.

Comment: As a Hint for the problem (once the typos are corrected):  Let $X$ be the event that you toss a game ending value.  Now look at the expected total value before $X$ occurs, and then consider the possible effects of the specific form $X$ took.

Comment: @lulu Thank you for raising that. I've fixed the typos now.

Comment: @lulu Please correct me if I'm wrong, but if we define $X$ like you say, then conditioning on the first throw results in $\mathbb{E}(X) = (1/2)(20/3 + \mathbb{E}(X)) + (1/2) \cdot 0 \implies \mathbb{E}(X) = 20/3$? Before I proceed is this correct?

Comment: I wouldn't try to condition on the first throw, though maybe that works.  I think it's easier than that, though.  How many trials do you expect before you get $X$?

Comment: @lulu Given that $3/6$ throws end the game, I'd assume that the expected length of a game is $2$ throws, so there would be $1$ throw before a game ending throw.

Comment: Exactly.  So, what's the expected value of the banked score (before we worry about whether you actually get it or not)?

Comment: @lulu Well, I'd assume that it'd just be $\$20/3$ per roll, as we have equal chance of winning $4$, $6$, or $10$.  Considering we expect only one roll, the expected value of the banked score would be $20/3$?

Comment: Indeed it is, so then what's the expected value of the game?

Comment: I have a feeling that I'm missing something extremely obvious, but I'm not sure how to proceed.

Comment: Almost there.  We've got a pile of money built up which you expect to be worth $\frac {20}3$.  What is the probability that you get it?  More broadly:  what is the probability that the game ends with a $4,6$ and not with a $1$?

Comment: There's a $2/3$ chance that I get it, and a $1/3$ chance that I lose it. Thus, I would expect to be paid $\$40/9$. This lines up with some code that I wrote and simulated on $10^7$ iterations!

Comment: @lulu Thank you for the detailed help, I really appreciate it! I'll formalise an answer to complete the thread :)

Comment: Perfect!  Good luck.

Answer (score 1):

Let's define $Y$ as the event that a game ending value $(1, 4, 6)$ has just been thrown. Well, on any arbitrary throw we have a $3/6 = 1/2$ chance of the game ending, from which we can expect the average game to go for $2$ rolls.

On the first of these rolls, the average payout is $\$20/3$. Thus, the average cumulative total before the game is ended is $\$ 20/3$. Upon the game ending throw, we keep our reward $2/3$ of the time, and lose it $1/3$ of the time.

Therefore, the expected winnings, is $2/3 \times 20/3 + 1/3 \times 0 = \$40 / 9$

A rather simple answer.

Answer (score 0):

**Remarks**

I saw your conversation with Lulu in the comment and I saw that you have obtained the correct answer. This is an alternative answer

**Solution**

Let $Y_{m}$ be a scenario where we roll $m$ times and the last roll is either $4$ or $6$. We have:

$$
\mathbb{P}\left(Y_{m}\right)=\frac{1}{2^{m-1}}\cdot\frac{1}{3}
$$

The expected value of earning, when we roll $m$ times is:

$$
\mathbb{E}\left(X\mid Y_{m}\right)=\frac{4+6+10}{3}\cdot\left(m-1\right)
$$

Therefore, the expected earning from the game is given by

$$
\begin{aligned}
\mathbb{E}\left(X\right)
&=
\sum_{m=2}^{\infty}\mathbb{E}\left(X\mid Y_{m}\right)\mathbb{P}\left(Y_{m}\right)\\
&=
\sum_{m=2}^{\infty}
\frac{20}{3}\cdot\left(m-1\right)\cdot\frac{1}{2^{m-1}}\cdot\frac{1}{3}\\
&=
\frac{20}{18}\cdot\sum_{m=2}^{\infty}\frac{m-1}{2^{m-2}}\\
&=\frac{20}{18}\cdot\left[\frac{d}{dx}\sum_{m=2}^{\infty}x^{m-1}\right]_{x=\frac{1}{2}}\\
&=\frac{20}{18}\cdot\left[\frac{d}{dx}\left(\frac{x}{1-x}\right)\right]_{x=\frac{1}{2}}\\
&=\frac{20}{18}\cdot\left[\frac{1}{\left(1-x\right)^{2}}\right]_{x=\frac{1}{2}}\\
&=\frac{40}{9}
\end{aligned}
$$